# Prove associative property of $\Bbb Z [x]$ ($\Bbb Z [x]$ is the set of all polynomials with variable x and integer coefficients)

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, associativity

I can't seem to find the answer anywhere to make sure the steps I did are right or wrong, and excuse me if the question is kinda dumb :")

I want to prove that $\Bbb Z [x]$ is a ring, so I want to prove associativity on $\Bbb Z [x]$ in addition.

$\Bbb Z [x]$ is the set of all polynomials with variable x and integer coefficients with the operations of polynomial addition and multiplication.

**I want to prove associativity in addition.**

All I did is :

1. assuming the following:
   $$ƒ(x) = a_n x^n + a_{n-1} x^{n-1} + … + a_1 x + a_0$$
   $$g(x) = b_m x^m + b_{m-1} x^{m-1} + … + b_1x + b_0$$
   $$h(x) = c_s x^s + c_{s-1} x^{s-1} + … + c_1x + c_0$$
   where $a_n , a_{n-1}, …, a_1, a_0, b_m , b_{m-1}, …, b_1, b_0, c_s , c_{s-1}, …, c_1, c_0 \in \Bbb Z$ and n is a non-negative integer.
2. I just said that $f(x) + (g(x) + h(x))$ and then equaled them to their values in my assumption.

That's it, that's where I don't know how I should continue to prove associativity in addition.

Comment: In $f(x)+(g(x)+h(x))$, group by $x^k$, using addition commutativity in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$, and multiplication distributivity over addition in $\mathbb{Z}$. Then you'll have $(a_k+(b_k+c_k))x^k$, which is equal to $((a_k+b_k)+c_k)x^k$ by associativity of addition in $\mathbb{Z}$, and you are done.

Comment: When thinking about it, commutativity of addition in polynomials is part of the definition of polynomials, not something which can be demonstrated. I.e. we could have another concept where $aX^2+bX+c$ is not the same as $bX+aX^2+c$. Never remarked that before. Actually it depends whether we talk about formal polynomials, or about polynomial functions. But this goes probably too far for the present discussion, sorry. :-)

Comment: great! but may I ask what $k$ equals? @Jean-ArmandMoroni

Comment: $k$ is an index, for example the "3" in $a_3x^3$. You'll have $\sum_{k=0}^N (a_k+(b_k+c_k))x^k$, where $N=\max(n,m,s)$.

Comment: Thank you so much @Jean-ArmandMoroni <3 I appreciate your help! ~